# removing nan from the datetime np.array: array extracted from datetime column with unique values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, datetime

I have following list has two values one is `datetime.datetime(2018-06-18)` and another `NaN`. both are extracted from the datetime column unique values . I just want list only contain the date.

```
# extracting date from datetime column
main_df['date'] = main_df.DateTime.dt.date 

# getting only unique values from date column
agg_hos =  main_df['date'].unique()

# output is
array([datetime.date(2018, 6, 18), NaT], dtype=object)
```

Want to remove the nan from the list
tried different ans from site
[remove nan values from np array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73728290/remove-nan-values-from-np-array)

```
# desired output
array([datetime.date(2018, 6, 18)], dtype=object)
```

How to do it?

Comment: note that `NaT` is a pandas type, not known to numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `pd.isnull` check instead (borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43475189/10197418)):

```py
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# np.isfinite(pd.NaT), np.isnan(pd.NaT)
# -> TypeError !

arr = np.array([datetime.date(2018, 6, 18), pd.NaT])

arr = arr[~pd.isnull(arr)]
# array([datetime.date(2018, 6, 18)], dtype=object)
```